# react-native-rtmp-publisher onConnectionFailed

Tags: react-native, video-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming

```
import RTMPPublisher, {
  RTMPPublisherRefProps,
  StreamState,
  BluetoothDeviceStatuses,
 } from 'react-native-rtmp-publisher';

const publisherRef = useRef<RTMPPublisherRefProps>(null);  
const url = 'rtmp://global-live.mux.com:443/app';

<RTMPPublisher
  ref={publisherRef}
  streamURL={url}
  streamName={stream_key}
  style={styles.publisher_camera}
  onDisconnect={handleOnDisconnect}
  onConnectionFailed={handleOnConnectionFailed}
  onConnectionStarted={handleOnConnectionStarted}
  onConnectionSuccess={handleOnConnectionSuccess}
  onNewBitrateReceived={handleOnNewBitrateReceived}
  onStreamStateChanged={handleOnStreamStateChanged}
  onBluetoothDeviceStatusChanged={handleBluetoothDeviceStatusChange}
 />
```

Error:: configure stream, Handshake error, unexpected 21 S0 received

The above error is received while calling "publisherRef.current.startStream();"

I tried different streamKey in streamName. what iam expecting is to create live stream in Mux

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the `react-native-rtmp-publisher` library to create a live stream with Mux. However, I noticed that there is an error in your code.

In this line:

```
const url = 'rtmp://global-live.mux.com:443/app';
```

You are trying to set the `url` variable to the RTMP server URL. However, you should replace `'rtmp://global-live.mux.com:443/app'` with your actual RTMP server URL.

Make sure to replace `'rtmp://global-live.mux.com:443/app'` with the URL of the RTMP server you want to stream to. This URL typically includes the protocol (`rtmp://`), the server hostname (e.g., `example.com`), the port number (e.g., `1935`), and the application name (e.g., `live`). Verify these details with your RTMP server provider, such as Mux.

Additionally, make sure to replace `stream_key` in `<RTMPPublisher />` component's `streamName` prop with your actual stream key from Mux Dashboard. This stream key uniquely identifies your stream on the RTMP server.

Once you have updated the code with the correct RTMP server URL and stream key, it should be ready for testing.

Comment: Based on MUX documentation [Link](https://docs.mux.com/guides/video/configure-broadcast-software) ,RTMP server URL is 'rtmp://global-live.mux.com:443/app'